# Performance enhancement for a Jquery Mobile web application

Tags: javascript, css, html, performance, jquery-mobile

What techniques can be implemented to improve the performance of a Jquery Mobile web application (no Phonegap, etc. has been used. Just a plain JQM mobile web application)? Things that we have already done include the following.

1. Minification of JS, CSS files.
2. Reduced or upto no images using font icons and image sprites.
3. Removed unwanted/unused CSS using mincss.
4. Used data-enhanced="true" wherever possible.
5. Used the latest JQM and JQuery libs (ofcourse =))
6. Page caching wherever possible.
7. Image scaling is not done. Different size images are sourced when required.

What else can be done to improve performance? What changes can we do in HTML, CSS and/or Javascript/Jquery/Jquery Mobile to further enhance the performance?

Regards.

Shreerang

Comment: Prefetching external pages.

Comment: @Omar that is done too. What can be improved in the code?

Comment: On google chrome, open developer tools, under Audits run a test to see the issues and warnings with your App.  You will see from the report that  (Things that we have already done) are not perfect. You can also try PageSpeed from google to test your apps performance --- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Answer (score 0):

A major item that I see missing from your list is reducing the number of elements on the page to the bare minimum. You probably have extra divs, spans, etc. on the page without even realizing it. Not only does the browser have to spend time rendering each element, if the style for a parent element is changed, the style for each child element must be recalculated as well!

A good way to look at your page to view nesting graphically is to check out the page using Firefox's 3D layout view: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View and check to see if any elements can be removed or combined.

References:

Yahoo best practices: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#min_dom

Google minimizing browser reflow: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow